# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null - jquery solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a div in my html code. When the user clicks a button, I execute a simple JS script where I try to hide it:

```
  document.getElementById("samplques").style.display = "none";
```

When executed, I get the error

> cannot read property style

I understand that the cause may be that the div has not loaded when the JS is executed. I tried putting the JS script at the bottom of the page, but that did not solve it.

Elsewhere on stackoverflow, people have suggested using jQuery. I am not skilled at jQuery, though I am using it occasionally.

Is using jQuery the answer? And if so, how would I accomplish my goal? If not, how do I solve this?

==============================================

Code snippet is here:

```
<div id="samplques" style="display:block">
samplques starts here - want to hide this when clicked below<p>

heading here<p>

<form>
<input type=radio onclick="posts('here')">click here</a><br>
</form><p>

samplques ends here<p>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
function posts(selected) {
    document.getElementById(samplques).style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

=============================================

JS error onclick is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

Comment: no, using jQuery is not the answer. It will only make your code do nothing with no errors. You need to fix the real problem - `document.getElementById` returning `null` while you expect it to find a DOM element.

Comment: because it does not find the element. So what is the code, what is the element you are trying to select? Either the element is not there when you try to read it or the id is not what you think it is or you have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: Without seeing your HTML, we can't say what the problem *is*. jQuery won't magically make `<div id="samplques">` exist when it didn't before.

Comment: At a guess? Sample question.

Comment: Nope; I always spell it that way when coding; thanks anyway.

Comment: Give the whole error. `Cannot read property style of undefined`?

Comment: `document.getElementById(samplques).style.display = 'none'` will only work if `samplques` is a variable defined somewhere else in your code (but not showing in the updated question). Changing to `document.getElementById("samplques").style.display = 'none'` should fix this.

Comment: Wow, Bryan -- it's the simple things I overlook. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

No. jQuery is just a library **built on** Javascript. Simply using jQuery **can never** just fix a problem, it can only make it *easier* (if anything).

If you're getting the error `can't read property 'style' of null`, it means `document.getElementById("samplques")` is returning `null`.

The cause is that an element with ID `samplques` doesn't exist.

Comment: Nope; samplques and its elements exist. I understand your point. That is why suggestions elsewhere to use jQuery confused me.

Comment: @user1852336 we need to see your HTML then

Answer (score 1):

So something like this? I did it with class names rather than id's, but is it possible you've misspelled the id? Edited to hide by ID, and show by class. Best of both worlds.

```js
var hideIt = function(){
  // var hideMe = document.getElementsByClassName("hideShow")[0];
  var hideMe = document.getElementById("sampleques");
  hideMe.style.display = "none";
  }

var showIt = function(){
  var hideMe = document.getElementsByClassName("hideShow")[0];
  hideMe.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hideIt()">Hide it!</button>
<button onClick="showIt()">Show it!</button>
<div class="hideShow" id="sampleques">Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula.</div>
```

Comment: OP is not asking _how_ to show/hide elements in JavaScript. OP is asking why trying to do so results in the `Cannot read property 'style' of null` error in their case.

Comment: This did it:                                                                                        <script type="text/javascript">
    function posts(selected) {

var hideMe = document.getElementById("samplques");
  hideMe.style.display = "none";
}
</script>                                                                                                                               donno why, but it works.... so far.

Comment: @user1852336, the code you just edited into your question has `document.getElementById(samplques).style.display = 'none'` with `samplques` not in quotes. So unless that is a variable defined elsewhere (but not shown in the updated code), you are essentially doing `document.getElementById(undefined).....` which of course doesn't find any elements, resulting in your error. This answer has `getElementById("samplques")` and thus actually finds your element.

Answer (score 0):

@Snowmonkey did a great job, but I would go a step further.

```js
var bool = true;
var hideMe = document.getElementById('hideShow');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

function hideIt() {
  if (bool) {
    hideMe.style.display = "none";
    bool = !bool;
    btn.innerHTML = 'Show!';
  } else {
    hideMe.style.display = "block";
    bool = !bool;
    btn.innerHTML = 'Hide!';
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hideIt()" id='btn'>Hide!</button>
<div id="hideShow">Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Pellentesque in
  ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Praesent sapien massa, convallis
  a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci
  luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula.</div>
```

Comment: OP is not asking _how_ to show/hide elements in JavaScript. OP is asking why trying to do so results in the `Cannot read property 'style' of null` error in their case.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your source, but you do not need jQuery. All that's needed is this:

```html
<script>
function hideDiv() {
    document.getElementById("samplques").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<button onclick="hideDiv()">CLICK ME</button>

<div id="samplques">CONTENT TO HIDE</div>
```

EDIT: that error you're getting is caused my a mismatch in your IDs that your targeting, or what your targeting is a class.

Comment: OP is not asking _how_ to show/hide elements in JavaScript. OP is asking why trying to do so results in the `Cannot read property 'style' of null` error in their case.

Comment: The level of detail provided in the question at the moment isn't enough to tell why. You did start your answer with, _"It's hard to say without seeing your source..."_ :) In other words, until the OP clarifies, everyone is just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

try this..[Style display Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp) or try
document.getElementById("samplques").style.display = 'none';

Comment: please clarify more your answer